# How to prevent button actions from happening too quickly in Kivy?

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, shell, kivy

Hey Guys I'm about 10 minutes new to Kivy and casually aquatinted with python.

I'm trying to create a button that calls a bash script I wrote to start a `radio` receiver (rtl-sdr). Calling it alone caused the GUI to freeze, so I decided to use threading. That worked fine, but then I found that I couldn't stop my process (rtl_fm)- something I needed to do in order to call another frequency.

I decided to use the `on_press` and `on_release` methods in Kivy to stop all my radio processes and attempt to start a new frequency thread - works well in theory, but the kill process is taking too long and I think its killing my `on_release` process before it has a chance to start. I have to press the button twice. (putting both `os.system` processes in a thread didn't help and neither did using the `Timer` method in the `threading` library) This is how I set it up - I may not need the thread in the `killRadio()`, but I was grasping at straws (sorry in advance):

(using `subprocess.call` wasn't working either)

**main.kv**

```
FloatLayout:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    Label:
            markup: True
            text: '[size=25]This app is for testing purposes.[/size]'
            pos: 0, 0

    MDRaisedButton:
            text: "106.9"
            font_size: 25
            on_press: app.killRadio()
            on_release: app.tuneRadio("106.9M")
            pos: 20, 255
            size_hint: .3, .3

    MDRaisedButton:
            text: "93.3"
            font_size: 25
            on_press: app.killRadio()
            on_release: app.tuneRadio("93.3M")
            pos: 305, 255
            size_hint: .3, .3
```

**main.py**

```
def killRadio(obj):
    de = Thread(target = lambda: os.system("kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep rtl_fm | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')"))
    try:
       de.start() 
    except:
        print ("can't kill")

def tuneRadio(obj, station):
    th = Thread(target = lambda: os.system('radio ' + station))
    # time.sleep(.3)
    th.start()
```

**radio bash**

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" = "stop" ] #thought this would kill the script - it just frees the cmd line
then
    echo "Stopping Radio Playback"
    exit 0
fi
if [ "$#" -gt 0  ]
then
    echo "playing {$1}"
    rtl_fm -f $1 -M wbfm -g 42 -s 200000 -r 192000 - | aplay -D hw:1,0 -c 2 -r 48000 -f S32_LE
else
    exit 0
fi
```

Using `Clock.schedule_once` and adding a delay seems to freeze the GUI, so I can't test if it works when pressing another button. Sorry, the code above is a desperate attempt to try everything - I simply want a button to kill the radio if its on and call another frequency.

I'm tired of reading Kivy and Python documentation - does anyone see whats missing? and I'm sure I'm doing something wrong...

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
def control_radio(self, *args):
    global radio
    radio_lock = threading.Lock()  # a mutex for the radio control
    if radio_lock.acquire(False):  # make sure other threads silently fail
        print("aquired")
        print(args)
        if radio and radio.poll() is None:  # kill the radio process if running
            print("radio and poll")
            radio.kill()  # use radio.terminate() for a milder version
        if args[0] == "tune":  # start the new radio process if requested
            print("tuning")
            radio = subprocess.Popen(["radio", args[1]])
        radio_lock.release()  # release the lock
```

I modified @zwer control function to the following to get it to work within my Main class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should really be using [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) so you can actually control your process without relying on flimsy external commands and the most basic way would be:

```
import subprocess

radio = None  # a reference to hold our radio process

def kill_radio(obj):
    if radio and radio.poll() is None:
        radio.kill()  # use radio.terminate() for a milder version

def tune_radio(obj, station):
    global radio
    if radio and radio.poll() is None:
        radio.kill()  # use radio.terminate() for a milder version
    radio = subprocess.Popen(["radio", station])
```

*Side note: I'd convert the whole `.sh` script to Python for considerably faster execution and easier control without the danger of orphaned processes.*

Now, the problem is that both [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) and [`subprocess.Popen.kill()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) are blocking methods so your functions wouldn't be returning until the process is started and terminated respectively. You can use fire-and-forget threads, as you've attempted, but you'll end up running a lot of threads waiting on their turn (plus you'd have to deal with queuing) so you need to decide what should happen when a user issues too much commands - disabling their controls until a process is started/terminated is probably the best as otherwise your app would be taking assumptions on behalf of the user.

That purely depends on how you laid out your controls and app GUI, tho, so the only other option (apart from queuing the commands) that I would propose is to just ignore calls to the underlying radio, be it tune or kill, while it's already starting/being terminated. Something like:

```
import subprocess
import threading

radio = None  # a reference to radio
radio_lock = threading.Lock()  # a mutex for the radio control

def control_radio(command, *args):
    global radio
    if radio_lock.acquire(False):  # make sure other threads silently fail
        if radio and radio.poll() is None:  # kill the radio process if running
            radio.kill()  # use radio.terminate() for a milder version
        if command == "tune":  # start the new radio process if requested
            radio = subprocess.Popen(["radio", args[0]])
        radio_lock.release()  # release the lock

def kill_radio(obj):
    threading.Thread(target=control_radio, args=("kill", )).start()

def tune_radio(obj, station):
    threading.Thread(target=control_radio, args=("tune", station)).start()
```

I would still discourage usage like this as it might end up with an oprhaned process if you forcibly kill your app or you don't wait for radio kill to execute. You mgiht want to at least add a blocking `if radio and radio.poll() is None: radio.terminate()` call when exiting your app just to make sure the spawned subprocess is killed off.

Comment: great. thanks for your answer! when calling `Thread(target=control_radio, args=("kill", )).start()` i get global name not defined control_radio. i tried self.control_radio but self was then not globally defined. any suggestions - sorry python is new to me. Does the `def` have to go below the `kill` and `tune` methods like some languages?

Comment: defining control_radio below the others doesnt help. I was wrong

Comment: @rcpilotp51 - Python is indent-sensitive so make sure everything is with the right indentation as in the above example.

Comment: i installed a linter and am still getting the same error. stinks

Comment: i think the linter is screwing me up. im using 2.7 and it may be looking for 3.x now it says that every function need self as first srgument - i dont know

Comment: @rcpilotp51 - if you're attempting to run these as a part of a class then you'll indeed need `self` as the first argument. Unfortunately, without the code itself I cannot tell you what's the actual problem.

Comment: I got it to work, but the entire process isnt killed - I get this `aplay: main:722: audio open error: Device or resource busy` and `Using device 0: Generic RTL2832U OEM
usb_claim_interface error -6
Failed to open rtlsdr device #0.'

Comment: I think I'm back at square one where the script terminates but the process within doesnt release the hardware for the next process to use